# Parametrization of a rotating surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, polar-coordinates, parametrization

What is the parametrization of a surface obtained by rotating the circle $(y − 3)^2 + z^2 = 1, x = 0$ about the z-axis.

I came up with the parametrization $S(r,θ) = (r , 3+cosθ , sinθ)$, is it correct?

Comment: Just an FYI, $r^2 \cos^2 (\theta) + \sin^2 (\theta) \neq 1$.

Comment: I meant cos! Thanks I edited it

Comment: No, it is not correct. A rotation about the $z$-axis is going to treat $x$ and $y$ symmetrically (in particular the same expression for both except cosine switching out with sine), but you don't see that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a half-plane that represents the rotation of the graph by $\phi$ from the $(+y)z$-halfplane. The horizontal direction on this half-plane is given by the unit vector $(\sin \phi, \cos \phi, 0)$. Call this the "s" axis. The intersection of this half-plane with the surface looks exactly like the same in all of the half-planes. In particular, like it does when $\phi = 0$ and $s = y$. That is, it has equation $(s-3)^2 + z^2 = 1$, which can be parametrized as $(s, z) = (3 + \cos \theta, sin \theta)$.

Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: So the parametrization I am getting now is $S(θ,ϕ) = ((3+cosθ)sinϕ,  (3+cosθ)cosϕ, sinθ)$ Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.